# How to sum all price values having in count the quantity of each one

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas, I would like to sum all of the price to get the count value for each one. The Dataframe looks like this:

```
   price  quantity
0     25         2
1     20         3
2     20        -1
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [25, 20, 20], 'quantity': [2, 3, -1]})
print(df)
```

So, I would expect the output to be something like $(25*2)+(20*3)+(20*-1)$:

```
>>> 90
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always call on the pandas DataFrame's columns and work with that.

```
values = df['price'] * df['quantity']
sum(values)
```

if you want more information, I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059094/i-want-to-multiply-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-add-the-result-into-a-n